# My app crashes.. in NSLog? Really?

Tags: ios, crash, nslog

That sounds very, very strange, but seems to be what this stack trace suggests.

Any ideas?

```
Thread: Unknown Name (Crashed)
0   0   libsystem_kernel.dylib              0x38a79350 __pthread_kill + 8
1   1   libsystem_c.dylib                   0x34002973 abort + 94
2   2   libsystem_c.dylib                   0x33fccf19 <redacted>
3   3   libsystem_c.dylib                   0x33fcd1dd <redacted> + 28
4   4   libsystem_c.dylib                   0x33f9977b <redacted> + 214
5   5   libsystem_c.dylib                   0x33f98773 <redacted> + 1198
6   6   libsystem_c.dylib                   0x33f98293 malloc_zone_malloc + 70
7   7   CoreFoundation                      0x36a32a10 <redacted> + 252
8   8   CoreFoundation                      0x36a33e4c <redacted> + 92
9   9   CoreFoundation                      0x3695b777 CFDictionarySetValue + 166
10  10  CoreFoundation                      0x36a27467 <redacted> + 102
11  11  CoreFoundation                      0x369a2347 CFCalendarCreateWithIdentifier + 534
12  12  CoreFoundation                      0x36a06f8b <redacted> + 106
13  13  CoreFoundation                      0x369ab021 _CFLogvEx + 188
14  14  Foundation                          0x347a5d8f NSLogv + 86
15  15  Foundation                          0x347a5d2f NSLog + 26
16  16  TypOHD                              0x000efe5f -[TypoViewControllerBase markIt:] (TypoViewControllerBase.m:325)
```

Here's why it's odd: All NSLog calls in the method use static NSString constants. Here's the method:

```
- (IBAction) markIt:(id)sender
{

    NSLog(@"Marking it");
    NSMutableArray *arr = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    NSRange visible = [self visibleRangeOfTextView:self.source];
    NSRange last = NSMakeRange(visible.location, 0);
    //    int cursorPos = self.textView.selectedRange.location;
    NSString *text = self.source.text;
    while (true) {
        NSRange error = [controller rangeOfMisspelledWordInString:text onlyInRange:visible startingAt:last.location + last.length];
        last = error;
        if (error.location == NSNotFound || error.length == 0) {
            break;
        }
        [arr addObject:[NSValue valueWithRange:error]];
    }
    NSLog(@"Spellchecked");

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.overlay.frame.size, NO, 0); 
    [[UIColor redColor] setStroke];
    UITextPosition *current = self.source.beginningOfDocument;
    int curTextPos = 0;
    CGFloat dash[] = {2.0f, 2.0f} ;
    int sourceLen = text.length;
    // Make the text ranges and mark them
    for (NSValue *val in arr) {
        NSRange range = [val rangeValue]; 
        if (range.location + range.length >= sourceLen) {
            break;
        }
        int toMove = range.location - curTextPos;
        UITextPosition *start = [self.source positionFromPosition:current offset:toMove];
        current = start;
        curTextPos = range.location;
        UITextPosition *end = [self.source positionFromPosition:start offset:range.length];

        UITextRange *textRange = [self.source textRangeFromPosition:start toPosition:end];
        CGRect rectInTextView = [self.source firstRectForRange:textRange];
        CGRect toDraw = rectInTextView;
        toDraw.origin.y -= self.source.contentOffset.y;
        UIBezierPath*    aPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
        [aPath setLineDash:dash count:2 phase:0];

        CGPoint lineStart = toDraw.origin;
        lineStart.y += toDraw.size.height;
        CGPoint lineEnd = lineStart;
        lineEnd.x += toDraw.size.width;

        [aPath moveToPoint:lineStart];
        [aPath addLineToPoint:lineEnd];
        [aPath stroke];        
    };
    self.overlay.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();    
    NSLog(@"Done");
}
```

EDIT:

Some digging in the log suggests that it's an out of memory condition that causes the later weirdness. But I suspect that the memory leaking isn't cause by this method in particular. As far as I can tell, it releases its context properly, right?

```
Oct  2 20:23:55 Admins-MacBook-Pro.local SkrivestotteHD[35780] <Error>: CGBitmapContextInfoCreate: unable to allocate 8552448 bytes for bitmap data
Oct  2 20:23:55 Admins-MacBook-Pro.local SkrivestotteHD[35780] <Error>: CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor: invalid context 0x0
Oct  2 20:23:55 Admins-MacBook-Pro.local SkrivestotteHD[35780] <Error>: CGContextSaveGState: invalid context 0x0
Oct  2 20:23:55 Admins-MacBook-Pro.local SkrivestotteHD[35780] <Error>: CGContextSetLineWidth: invalid context 0x0
Oct  2 20:23:55 Admins-MacBook-Pro.local SkrivestotteHD[35780] <Error>: CGContextSetLineJoin: invalid context 0x0
Oct  2 20:23:55 Admins-MacBook-Pro.local SkrivestotteHD[35780] <Error>: CGContextSetLineCap: invalid context 0x0
Oct  2 20:23:55 Admins-MacBook-Pro.local SkrivestotteHD[35780] <Error>: CGContextSetMiterLimit: invalid context 0x0
Oct  2 20:23:55 Admins-MacBook-Pro.local SkrivestotteHD[35780] <Error>: CGContextSetFlatness: invalid context 0x0
Oct  2 20:23:55 Admins-MacBook-Pro.local SkrivestotteHD[35780] <Error>: CGContextSetLineDash: invalid context 0x0
Oct  2 20:23:55 Admins-MacBook-Pro.local SkrivestotteHD[35780] <Error>: CGContextAddPath: invalid context 0x0
Oct  2 20:23:55 Admins-MacBook-Pro.local SkrivestotteHD[35780] <Error>: CGContextDrawPath: invalid context 0x0
Oct  2 20:23:55 Admins-MacBook-Pro.local SkrivestotteHD[35780] <Error>: CGContextRestoreGState: invalid context 0x0
Oct  2 20:23:55 Admins-MacBook-Pro.local SkrivestotteHD[35780] <Error>: CGContextSaveGState: invalid context 0x0
Oct  2 20:23:55 Admins-MacBook-Pro.local SkrivestotteHD[35780] <Error>: CGContextSetLineWidth: invalid context 0x0
Oct  2 20:23:55 Admins-MacBook-Pro.local SkrivestotteHD[35780] <Error>: CGContextSetLineJoin: invalid context 0x0
Oct  2 20:23:55 Admins-MacBook-Pro.local SkrivestotteHD[35780] <Error>: CGContextSetLineCap: invalid context 0x0
Oct  2 20:23:55 Admins-MacBook-Pro.local SkrivestotteHD[35780] <Error>: CGContextSetMiterLimit: invalid context 0x0
Oct  2 20:23:55 Admins-MacBook-Pro.local SkrivestotteHD[35780] <Error>: CGContextSetFlatness: invalid context 0x0
Oct  2 20:23:55 Admins-MacBook-Pro.local SkrivestotteHD[35780] <Error>: CGContextSetLineDash: invalid context 0x0
Oct  2 20:23:55 Admins-MacBook-Pro.local SkrivestotteHD[35780] <Error>: CGContextAddPath: invalid context 0x0
Oct  2 20:23:55 Admins-MacBook-Pro.local SkrivestotteHD[35780] <Error>: CGContextDrawPath: invalid context 0x0
Oct  2 20:23:55 Admins-MacBook-Pro.local SkrivestotteHD[35780] <Error>: CGContextRestoreGState: invalid context 0x0
Oct  2 20:23:55 Admins-MacBook-Pro.local SkrivestotteHD[35780] <Error>: CGContextSaveGState: invalid context 0x0
Oct  2 20:23:55 Admins-MacBook-Pro.local SkrivestotteHD[35780] <Error>: CGContextSetLineWidth: invalid context 0x0
Oct  2 20:23:55 Admins-MacBook-Pro.local SkrivestotteHD[35780] <Error>: CGContextSetLineJoin: invalid context 0x0
Oct  2 20:23:55 Admins-MacBook-Pro.local SkrivestotteHD[35780] <Error>: CGContextSetLineCap: invalid context 0x0
Oct  2 20:23:55 Admins-MacBook-Pro.local SkrivestotteHD[35780] <Error>: CGContextSetMiterLimit: invalid context 0x0
Oct  2 20:23:55 Admins-MacBook-Pro.local SkrivestotteHD[35780] <Error>: CGContextSetFlatness: invalid context 0x0
Oct  2 20:23:55 Admins-MacBook-Pro.local SkrivestotteHD[35780] <Error>: CGContextSetLineDash: invalid context 0x0
Oct  2 20:23:55 Admins-MacBook-Pro.local SkrivestotteHD[35780] <Error>: CGContextAddPath: invalid context 0x0
Oct  2 20:23:55 Admins-MacBook-Pro.local SkrivestotteHD[35780] <Error>: CGContextDrawPath: invalid context 0x0
Oct  2 20:23:55 Admins-MacBook-Pro.local SkrivestotteHD[35780] <Error>: CGContextRestoreGState: invalid context 0x0
Oct  2 20:23:55 Admins-MacBook-Pro.local SkrivestotteHD[35780] <Error>: CGContextSaveGState: invalid context 0x0
Oct  2 20:23:55 Admins-MacBook-Pro.local SkrivestotteHD[35780] <Error>: CGContextSetLineWidth: invalid context 0x0
Oct  2 20:23:55 Admins-MacBook-Pro.local SkrivestotteHD[35780] <Error>: CGContextSetLineJoin: invalid context 0x0
Oct  2 20:23:55 Admins-MacBook-Pro.local SkrivestotteHD[35780] <Error>: CGContextSetLineCap: invalid context 0x0
Oct  2 20:23:55 Admins-MacBook-Pro.local SkrivestotteHD[35780] <Error>: CGContextSetMiterLimit: invalid context 0x0
Oct  2 20:23:55 Admins-MacBook-Pro.local SkrivestotteHD[35780] <Error>: CGContextSetFlatness: invalid context 0x0
Oct  2 20:23:55 Admins-MacBook-Pro.local SkrivestotteHD[35780] <Error>: CGContextSetLineDash: invalid context 0x0
Oct  2 20:23:55 Admins-MacBook-Pro.local SkrivestotteHD[35780] <Error>: CGContextAddPath: invalid context 0x0
Oct  2 20:23:55 Admins-MacBook-Pro.local SkrivestotteHD[35780] <Error>: CGContextDrawPath: invalid context 0x0
Oct  2 20:23:55 Admins-MacBook-Pro.local SkrivestotteHD[35780] <Error>: CGContextRestoreGState: invalid context 0x0
Oct  2 20:23:55 Admins-MacBook-Pro.local SkrivestotteHD[35780] <Error>: CGContextSaveGState: invalid context 0x0
Oct  2 20:23:55 Admins-MacBook-Pro.local SkrivestotteHD[35780] <Error>: CGContextSetLineWidth: invalid context 0x0
Oct  2 20:23:55 Admins-MacBook-Pro.local SkrivestotteHD[35780] <Error>: CGContextSetLineJoin: invalid context 0x0
Oct  2 20:23:55 Admins-MacBook-Pro.local SkrivestotteHD[35780] <Error>: CGContextSetLineCap: invalid context 0x0
Oct  2 20:23:55 Admins-MacBook-Pro.local SkrivestotteHD[35780] <Error>: CGContextSetMiterLimit: invalid context 0x0
Oct  2 20:23:55 Admins-MacBook-Pro.local SkrivestotteHD[35780] <Error>: CGContextSetFlatness: invalid context 0x0
Oct  2 20:23:55 Admins-MacBook-Pro.local SkrivestotteHD[35780] <Error>: CGContextSetLineDash: invalid context 0x0
Oct  2 20:23:55 Admins-MacBook-Pro.local SkrivestotteHD[35780] <Error>: CGContextAddPath: invalid context 0x0
Oct  2 20:23:55 Admins-MacBook-Pro.local SkrivestotteHD[35780] <Error>: CGContextDrawPath: invalid context 0x0
Oct  2 20:23:55 Admins-MacBook-Pro.local SkrivestotteHD[35780] <Error>: CGContextRestoreGState: invalid context 0x0
Oct  2 20:23:55 Admins-MacBook-Pro.local SkrivestotteHD[35780] <Error>: CGContextSaveGState: invalid context 0x0
Oct  2 20:23:55 Admins-MacBook-Pro.local SkrivestotteHD[35780] <Error>: CGContextSetLineWidth: invalid context 0x0
Oct  2 20:23:55 Admins-MacBook-Pro.local SkrivestotteHD[35780] <Error>: CGContextSetLineJoin: invalid context 0x0
Oct  2 20:23:55 Admins-MacBook-Pro.local SkrivestotteHD[35780] <Error>: CGContextSetLineCap: invalid context 0x0
Oct  2 20:23:55 Admins-MacBook-Pro.local SkrivestotteHD[35780] <Error>: CGContextSetMiterLimit: invalid context 0x0
Oct  2 20:23:55 Admins-MacBook-Pro.local SkrivestotteHD[35780] <Error>: CGContextSetFlatness: invalid context 0x0
Oct  2 20:23:55 Admins-MacBook-Pro.local SkrivestotteHD[35780] <Error>: CGContextSetLineDash: invalid context 0x0
Oct  2 20:23:55 Admins-MacBook-Pro.local SkrivestotteHD[35780] <Error>: CGContextAddPath: invalid context 0x0
Oct  2 20:23:55 Admins-MacBook-Pro.local SkrivestotteHD[35780] <Error>: CGContextDrawPath: invalid context 0x0
Oct  2 20:23:55 Admins-MacBook-Pro.local SkrivestotteHD[35780] <Error>: CGContextRestoreGState: invalid context 0x0
Oct  2 20:23:55 Admins-MacBook-Pro.local SkrivestotteHD[35780] <Error>: CGContextSaveGState: invalid context 0x0
Oct  2 20:23:55 Admins-MacBook-Pro.local SkrivestotteHD[35780] <Error>: CGContextSetLineWidth: invalid context 0x0
Oct  2 20:23:55 Admins-MacBook-Pro.local SkrivestotteHD[35780] <Error>: CGContextSetLineJoin: invalid context 0x0
Oct  2 20:23:55 Admins-MacBook-Pro.local SkrivestotteHD[35780] <Error>: CGContextSetLineCap: invalid context 0x0
Oct  2 20:23:55 Admins-MacBook-Pro.local SkrivestotteHD[35780] <Error>: CGContextSetMiterLimit: invalid context 0x0
Oct  2 20:23:55 Admins-MacBook-Pro.local SkrivestotteHD[35780] <Error>: CGContextSetFlatness: invalid context 0x0
Oct  2 20:23:55 Admins-MacBook-Pro.local SkrivestotteHD[35780] <Error>: CGContextSetLineDash: invalid context 0x0
Oct  2 20:23:55 Admins-MacBook-Pro.local SkrivestotteHD[35780] <Error>: CGContextAddPath: invalid context 0x0
Oct  2 20:23:55 Admins-MacBook-Pro.local SkrivestotteHD[35780] <Error>: CGContextDrawPath: invalid context 0x0
Oct  2 20:23:55 Admins-MacBook-Pro.local SkrivestotteHD[35780] <Error>: CGContextRestoreGState: invalid context 0x0
2
```

Setting a breakpoint in malloc_error_break tells me that the out of memory condition is caused by this line:

```
CGRect rectInTextView = [self.source firstRectForRange:textRange];
```

Or rather, in particular the firstRectForRange method.

HOWEVER:
Commenting out the entire markIt method just moves the out of memory condition elsewhere. I guess it's time to really learn how to use the XCode tools to find memory leaks.

Comment: Some code would be helpful.. whats on this line? (TypoViewControllerBase.m:325)

Comment: how does your NSLog look like? And the code surrounding it?

Comment: comment your log and check weather it works or not

Comment: You are using invalid context for drawing means , to draw you can get a valid context  inside DrawRect method only

Comment: You're allocating too much memory. Use instruments (allocation tool) to see your memory usage. The image context needs more than 8MB memory. I guess you're running on iPad3 simulator.

Comment: phix23 Yes I'm allocating too much memory, but the image context is only a symptom. When I remove it, the program eventually crashes elsewhere with a memory allocation error.